# Non-US Keyboard and CMD + SHIFT + 7

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-mountain-lion, shortcuts

I have a Swiss keyboard and in many (developer-based) programs I get a conflict with one of my favorite shortcuts: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. I use this to set the focus to every OSX application's `Help > Search` menu entry, where I can search and execute any commands without having to use the mouse.

So for example in Textmate or Xcode this shortcut makes comments from the selected text, rather than jumping to `Help > Search`.

Now I don't want to do this for every program (A setting I would loose on a new Mac again). So is there a global way to set the `Help > Search`-Shortcut as the master?

http://i.minus.com/jkwRLQzLVQpSt.png

Comment: Why not use the default `cmd-?` For the search?

Comment: @DanielBeck I don't want to search, but rather filter the menu items. I added a screenshot for clarity

Comment: It's the same feature (see the *Search* label to the left, and search results in the *Help Topics* section below menu items). AFAIK the default shortcut for this is `Cmd-?` -- see *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts*. Hence the question why you don't just use that instead to prevent collision with quite a few programs.

Comment: Apparently the default shortcut is `Cmd-Shift-/` and that works out to `Cmd-?` on International English and US keyboards. It's probably simply not adapted for non-US keyboards, similar to the window switcher `Cmd-Backtick`. I'd still suggest you set it to `Cmd-?`, which probably prevents quite a few shortcut collisions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest option would be to just change the help menu shortcut:

[image]

You could use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to change ⇧⌘7 to ⇧⌘ß:

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::MINUS, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

You can also configure shortcuts using a shell script like this:

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Comment Selection" = "@-"; // cmd-minus
"Toggle Comment" = "@-";
}'
```

In TextMate the shortcuts for bundle items have precedence though.